# Is SELECT keyword still case sensitive in MySQL query cache?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

The Query Performance chapter from High Performance MySQL book (2004) said MySQL(4.0.1) attempts to locate the results of any 'SELECT' query in the query cache before bothering to analyze or execute it. MySQL uses the exact query text it receives, so the cache is sensitive, which means

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

is different from

```
select * FROM table1
```

I'd like to know if this still is the case in MySQL 5.x, so we should always type 'SELECT' instead of 'select'.

Comment: @Everyone, give him a break on this question. Yes, it's a poorly constructed question, but it is his first time here. AT grisson, it's obvious that if you had taken five seconds to try this on your own, this question would be non-existent in the first place. So, please, next time try a little on your own before asking.

Thanks.

Comment: beside a lot of other questions, this is a valid question AND IS PROPER TAGED !!!! +1 for this :-) many other new users would have added the programming language they try this to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not, but you would know that if you tried it!

**EDIT:**
Neither are the following, just in case you were wondering.

1. Insert
2. Where
3. From
4. Select (above)
5. Order
6. Any of the others!

Comment: Apparently it is, and you would know that if you looked it up. See @William Riley's answer.

Comment: Yes, the `cache` is case sensitive, but the query will still run regardless of the case. I believe that the user updated his original question so you know.

Answer (score 5):

The MySQL query cache is [case (and byte) sensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-operation.html).

> Incoming queries are compared to those in the query cache before parsing, so the following two queries are regarded as different by the query cache:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name
> Select * from tbl_name
> ```
>
> Queries must be exactly the same (byte for byte) to be seen as identical. In addition, query strings that are identical may be treated as different for other reasons. Queries that use different databases, different protocol versions, or different default character sets are considered different queries and are cached separately.